# Android Studio 4.1.1 "Cannot access android.app.Activity" on Windows 10

Tags: android, ide

I have just downloaded AS 4.1.1 and created a new project with "Empty Activity", left the default name and Minimum SDK with defaults.
I get the error in the subject. this is the view of the project:

[image]

I made absolutely no change. For the fun of it, I tried "Make project". Nothing happens, no output window to show the build progress/errors, like you would see in most IDEs.

Thanks for your help,
Michel

Comment: I tried on my Macbook, same error.

Comment: What are the default name and Min SDK? And did you already download any SDKs ?(via the SDK Manager, a small button with a cube and a downward pointing arrow)

Comment: Default name: My Application, Min SDK: 18. According to some people after googling it, the SDK is automatically installed with this version of AS. Is is located in <user>\AppData\Local\Android\SDK

Comment: Other things I tried, downgrade the JDK from 13 to 8. Same error

Comment: Sorry but remote support is difficult :(  I found a step by step guide [https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config), maybe this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. At first, I upgraded from 3 to 4.1.1. Then I uninstalled AS 4.1.1 and downloaded a fresh install. Still the problem persisted.
I uninstalled again, but this time, I searched for anything Android-related stuff and deleted it, including the SDK under %APP_DATA%\Local\Android\Sdk.
When I re-installed, it prompted me for SDK installation. Selected the SDK and finished installation.
I re-created the application and the error is now gone.
Frankly, I pity the newbie to which this could happen.