# Android studio have a problem when create new kotlin app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

When i create a new kotlin app (blank app), after gradle run, the all code default is covered with red line.
[image]

My gradle project: [image]

My gradle module: [image] [image]

Comment: Close the project and reopen it

Comment: Is the Android SDK properly installed on your machine?

Comment: what about manifest? are there any errors in that?

Comment: yes, i close and reopen but it still error.

Comment: before you give an effort to create a question, I suggest you to type your problem on google. 

I found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65496655/11021522) that might be same as your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.